# Ошибка при заполнении поля массива значениями

Tags: php, массивы

Создаю массив и заполняю его полями, но страница вешается. Что не так?

```
$products = array();
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $products[] = [
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'price' => (int)$item['line_total'],
    ];
}
```

Значения в компонентах присутствуют, т.к. если через переменные обращаться, то всё работает:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $product_name = $item['name'];
    $product_quantity = $item['qty'];
    $product_price = (int)$item['line_total'];
}
```

И вот такая запись работает, но мне не нужно плодить много массивов `$products`:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $products = array(
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'price' => (int)$item['line_total']
    );
}
```

Comment: Не похоже что ошибка в приведенном Вами коде. Скорее всего чтобы Вам помочь нужно больше информации.

Comment: В логах ошибку искали? Может быть ваша версия PHP не поддерживает короткий синтаксис массивов - через [] ?

Comment: @Witalij Kaa ну как это: код удаляю - страница загружается, возвращаю обратно - снова пустая..

Comment: @artoodetoo версия php 5.4 как в логах искать ошибку?

Comment: @artoodetoo а как можно без [] заполнить массив, чтобы не создавать тьму одинаковых, как у меня в описании?

Comment: @Вася а `$products[] = array(` пробовали?

Comment: @Вася переключитесь на php 5.6 если нет задачи разрабатывать специально для 5.4 а короткий синтаксис массивов появился именно в 5.4. а вообще мне кажется у Вас проблемы не связанные с приведенным кодом. и тут очень подробно нужно разбираться...

Comment: @Regent спасибо, вот так работает! теперь не нужно указывать вверху  `$products = array();` ?

Comment: @Witalij Kaa связаны, т.к. подсказка выше прокатила!

Comment: @Вася на здоровье. Почему не нужно? Я в PHP не разбираюсь, но вроде `$products = array();` - это создание массива, а `$products[] = array( ... );` - добавление массива в качестве элемента в конец `$products`?

Comment: Я уже запутался с вашими скобками и множеством правок вопроса )))

Comment: @Regent, я вас обоих имел в виду ;)

Comment: @Regent, да ладно,оставим это. Я выразил свою эмоциональную оценку. Никаких обвинений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если версия php ниже 5.4 то нельзя использовать короткую запись для массивов

```
$products = array();
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $products[] = array(
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'price' => (int)$item['line_total'],
    );
}
```

### Дополнение

Во-вторых всегда смотрите логи в первую очередь